# This code don't run on other compiler except vscode

Tags: c, stack

The giver code is for converting infix to postfix using stack. I tried it everywhere no errors or warning were shown except for one time there was a segmentation fault on my school's computer. If anyone can explain the correct way to write the code it'll be very helpful as I'm unable to find.
In code we scan the infix expression and check if it's an operator and then if it is an operator we push it to stack and character or digit go to an array. We then pop the operator from the stack if we find another operator of more precedence than the previous pushed operator and we keep popping till we get less precedence operator in stack and append it to the array that is also our output.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include<ctype.h>

struct stack
{
    int size;
    int top;
    char *arr;
};
int stacktop(struct stack *sp)
{
    return sp->arr[sp->top];
}
void push(struct stack *ptr, char val)
{
    if (ptr->top == ptr->size - 1)
    {
        printf("Stack is full\n");
    }
    else
    {
        ptr->top++;
        ptr->arr[ptr->top] = val;
    }
}
char pop(struct stack *ptr)
{
    int a;
    if (ptr->top == -1)
    {
        printf("\n");
    }
    else
    {
        a = ptr->arr[ptr->top];
        ptr->top--;
        return a;
    }
}
int isoperator(char symbol)
{
    if (symbol == '^' || symbol == '*' || symbol == '/' || symbol == '+' || symbol == '-')
    {
        return 1;
    }
    else
    {
        return 0;
    }
}
int precedence(char symbol)
{
    if (symbol == '^')
    {
        return (3);
    }
    else if (symbol == '*' || symbol == '/')
    {
        return (2);
    }
    else if (symbol == '-' || symbol == '+')
    {
        return (1);
    }
    else
    {
        return (0);
    }
}
char *infix_to_postfix(char *infix)
{
    struct stack *sp = (struct stack *)malloc(sizeof(struct stack));
    sp->size = 50;
    sp->top = -1;
    sp->arr = (char *)malloc(sp->size * sizeof(char));
    char *postfix = (char *)malloc(strlen((infix) + 1) * sizeof(char));
    int i = 0, j = 0, x = 0;
    while (infix[i] != '\0')
    {
        if (infix[i] == '(')
        {
            push(sp, infix[i]);
        }
        else if( isdigit(infix[i]) || isalpha(infix[i])){
            postfix[j]=infix[i];
            j++;
        }
        else if (isoperator(infix[i])==1)
        {
            x=pop(sp);
            while(isoperator(x)==1 && precedence(x)>=precedence(infix[i])){
                postfix[j]=x;
                j++;
                x=pop(sp);
            }
            push(sp, x);
            push(sp, infix[i]);
        }
        else if (infix[i] == ')')
        {
            x = pop(sp);
            while (x != '(')
            {
                postfix[j] = x;
                j++;
                x = pop(sp);
            }
        }
        i++;
    }
    while (!(sp->top == -1))
    {
        postfix[j] = pop(sp);
        j++;
    }
    postfix[j] = '\0';
    return postfix;
}

int main()
{
    char *infix;
    printf("Enter your expression\n");
    scanf("%s",infix);
    printf("Postfix is %s", infix_to_postfix(infix));
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: use the debugger, luke

Comment: `infix` is uninitialized in `main()`, and you're using it to catch input. That's a serious problem. Also, `pop()` doesn't necessarily return a value. Compile warnings showed me those problems.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The pointer variable `char *infix` doesn't point to anything so it's not about VSCode and other compilers. It's complete luck that it's working on VSCode.

You should allocate some memory either statically `char infix[100]` or dynamically `char *infix = (char *)malloc(100)`.

Also, you have a problem with `pop` function. You shouöd always return a `char` from this function not only under certain conditions.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help.  :)